# I am working as a consultant in a/in/in the corporate sector?

Tags: articles, nouns, uncountable-nouns

> I am working as a consultant **in a**/**in**/**in the** corporate sector?

Which one is right? what does the sentence mean with articles and without articles? can the corporate sector be an uncountable noun?

And when someone says *I am working as a consultant in the corporate sector*, with the use of "the" what does the sentence mean? Is the corporate sector still an uncountable noun here?

Answer (score 1):

"Corporate sector" refers to the part of **a country's** economic activity that involves private companies. Therefore, each country only has **one** 'corporate sector'.

As there is only one that you could likely work in, the definite article is appropriate - "I work in *the* corporate sector".

Of course, the corporate sector encompasses all the many private businesses in that country, so you might say "I work for **a** company in **the** private sector".